# Applying Bootstrap style to Asp.net Controls

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a simple web project using asp.net 4.5 , c# and Bootstrap

My frontend is simply a Master page/default page with some static content (navbar, sidebar, footer etc) while the Page title and content are retrieved from an mdb database.
I tried to make a couple of pages and everything seemed to work fine, but i just realized that the style applied on an ASP.NET web control is not rendered.
Note that i'm still putting the content in the db by hand as the editor is not yet done.

Examples:

```
<i>prova tag &lt;i&gt;</i> This works (default styling)
<asp:button CssClass="btn btn-large">Test Button</asp:button> (This does not work      (simple, unstyled text is shown)
<asp:label>Prova Roba strana</asp:label> (This works (because it uses the default styling)
<input type=password/> (This works)
<code>&lt;section&gt;</code> (This works)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're missing `runat="server"` for a start. What's the rendered HTML you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Here is two examples of doing buttons with a bootstrap theme.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-large">Test</button>
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Test Button" CssClass="btn btn-large" />
```

I would guess you're mixing the two together and the hybrid isn't valid, which is why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

use instead

`<asp:button class="btn btn-large">Test Button</asp:button>`

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.